# A question about some detail in Peskin and Schroeder's book

Tags: kinematics, field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I have a question in Peskin and Schroeder's book (Quantum field theory) page 46. Why
$$\big[ \sqrt{E+p^3}(\frac{1-\sigma^3}{2})+\sqrt{E-p^3}(\frac{1+\sigma^3}{2})\Big]=\sqrt{p.\sigma}~?$$
and why $$(p\cdot \sigma )(p\cdot \bar{\sigma})=p^2~?$$

I don't understand the meaning of $\sqrt{p\cdot \sigma}$. I'd really appreciate if someone could explain me.

**What I've tried:** Because we have a boost along the 3-direction, $p=(E,0,0,p^3)$. So $p\cdot \sigma^{\mu}=(E,0,0,p^3)\cdot (1,\sigma)=E-p^3 \sigma^3=‎\begin{pmatrix}
E-p^3 & 0 \\ 0 & E+p^3
\end{pmatrix}‎$. Thus we have ‎$$\sqrt{p‎\cdot ‎‎\sigma}‎ ‎=‎\begin{pmatrix}
‎\sqrt{E-p^3}‎ & 0 \\ 0 & ‎\sqrt{E+p^3}‎
\end{pmatrix}‎.$$

Comment: This is three different questions.

Comment: Did you notice that on page 45 it says “Consider a boost along the 3-direction”? The first equation does not hold for arbitrary $p$.

Comment: @Ghoster Sorry about that but I need help to understand it.

Comment: Since your post asks three different questions, it may get closed for being unfocused. Then you may not get an answer to any of them.

Comment: @Ghoster Yes, I've read it. If not, why deos the author says that the last line can be simplified to give (between 3.49 and 3.50)?

Comment: @Ghoster You are right. Consider it done. I'll edit my question.

Comment: It can be simplified when $p=(E,0,0,p^3)$, which is what $p=(m,0,0,0)$ looks like after a boost in the 3-direction.

Comment: @Ghoster Got it. I'll check it again. Thank you so much for your help. Can I ask questions if I have problem again?

Comment: Comments are not the place to keep asking questions.

Comment: @Ghoster I really appreciate your favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read quite a large proportion of Peskin and Schroeder's book on Quantum Field Theory (P&S) and I do not recall the first equation you write. So, I will sketch a proof for the second one. If there are still questions, please let me know in the comments.

Consider two four vectors, whose spatial components are Pauli matrices

$$\sigma^{\mu}=(\mathbb{1},\sigma^i)
\hspace{3em}
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}=(\mathbb{1},-\sigma^i)$$

where $1$ is the 2x2 unit matrix.

Now consider the dot products

1. $p\cdot\sigma=p^01-p^1\sigma^1-p^2\sigma^2-p^3\sigma^3=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   p^0 & 0 \\
   0 & p^0 
   \end{pmatrix}-
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & p^1 \\
   p^1 & 0 
   \end{pmatrix}-
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -ip^2 \\
   ip^2 & 0 
   \end{pmatrix}-
   \begin{pmatrix}
   p^3 & 0 \\
   0 & -p^3 
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   p^0-p^3 & -p^1+ip^2 \\
   -p^1-ip^2 & p^0+p^3 
   \end{pmatrix}$
2. $p\cdot\bar{\sigma}=p^01+p^1\sigma^1+p^2\sigma^2+p^3\sigma^3=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   p^0 & 0 \\
   0 & p^0 
   \end{pmatrix}+
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & p^1 \\
   p^1 & 0 
   \end{pmatrix}+
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -ip^2 \\
   ip^2 & 0 
   \end{pmatrix}+
   \begin{pmatrix}
   p^3 & 0 \\
   0 & -p^3 
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   p^0+p^3 & p^1-ip^2 \\
   p^1+ip^2 & p^0-p^3 
   \end{pmatrix}$

Hence, we multiply
$$(p\cdot\sigma)(p\cdot\bar{\sigma})=
\begin{pmatrix}
p^0-p^3 & -p^1+ip^2 \\
-p^1-ip^2 & p^0+p^3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p^0+p^3 & p^1-ip^2 \\
p^1+ip^2 & p^0-p^3 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
(p^0)^2-(p^3)^2-(p^1)^2-(p^2)^2 & 0 \\
0 & (p^0)^2-(p^3)^2-(p^1)^2-(p^2)^2 
\end{pmatrix}=p^2\times 1$$

The meaning of $\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma\:\vphantom{tfrac{a}{b}}}$ is such that
$$\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma\:\vphantom{tfrac{a}{b}}}\sqrt{p\cdot\bar{\sigma}\:\vphantom{tfrac{a}{b}}}=\sqrt{p^2}=m$$
for particles that are on-shell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice explanation. I got it completey. Appreciate it.